# Loosing sound from you tube backing track whilst playing electric guitar using Bias FX2

Tags: guitar, software, audio

When I play Guitar, I use Bias FX2 software through my Pre Sonus Monitors and Pre Sonus AudioBox interface, all through my PC, Windows 10 so, I like to play along using You Tube Backing Tracks but, sometimes when I crank up my guitar volume, on guitar and on the interface volume the You Tube backing tracks volume level seems to drop at least by half so, what would cause this drop in volume level of my you tube backing track when I play my guitar?                                                                                                        my guitar volume level is fine but my PC volume level seems to drop.                                              I have checked PC Audio settings,Bias FX2 Audio Settings but, can't figure it out, would my monitors volume levels drop for some reason, like if they were overloaded?

Comment: This is probably more suited to Super User, as it's a computer issue not a music issue. See https://superuser.com/questions/1655953/sound-compression-is-on-despite-volume-leveling-being-switched-off-in-windows-10 for probable cause. Windows does all sorts of 'helpful' consumer stuff by default, that you have to switch off for proper work.

Comment: Computer displays the same volume level on WIndows even the real volume of the backing track has dropped down? or the volume indicator on Windows also drops along with the real volume? If it's the secont scenario, have you checked spliting volume controls to determine if the volume drops only for browser, or if applies to master windows volume? And the last question, if you try using VLC or similar software (instead of a browser) to play a backtrack, does the same issue araise?